# Building Hadoop 2.9.0 on Raspberry 3

Tags: pi-3

I tried to build Hadoop 2.9.0 based on this article:
http://www.widriksson.com/raspberry-pi-2-hadoop-2-cluster/

While building the Hadoop sources, I ran into a problem that may or may not be related to Hadoop itself.
The error I get is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

during execution of this build command:

```
sudo mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar
```

The command that leads to the error is:

```
/bin/sh -c cd /home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common && "/home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah" -d /home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native/javah -classpath /home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/classes:/home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/target/hadoop-annotations-2.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/../lib/tools.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-sslengine/6.1.26/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.13/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.13/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/root/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.0/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/jamesmurty/utils/java-xmlbuilder/0.4/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/target/hadoop-auth-2.7.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.7.1/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.7.1/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.7.1/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibCompressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.bzip2.Bzip2Compressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.bzip2.Bzip2Decompressor org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.SharedFileDescriptorFactory org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsNetgroupMapping org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyCompressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Compressor org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Decompressor org.apache.hadoop.crypto.OpensslCipher org.apache.hadoop.crypto.random.OpensslSecureRandom org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32 org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocket org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher
```

The part that looks suspicious to me is right at the beginning of the command:

```
/home/pi/hadoop-2.7.4-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah
```

Maybe JAVA_HOME is not correctly substituted?
Here is some background information about the system:

Raspberry 3 Model B

```
uname -a:
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt

mvn -v:
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /home/pi/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.9.59-v7+", arch: "arm", family: "unix"
```

At the moment, I have no idea what I can do to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in build hadoop-2.9.0 on my raspi 3.
my PI uname -a is

> 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

I installed oracle-java8-jdk, cmake, git, libc6-dev

I created an hduser user

From a previous build (2.7.3) i've compiled and installed protobuf

I downloaded and untarziped apache-maven-3.5.2 in the hduser homedir

I downloaded in this directory hadoop-2.9.0-src.tar.gz.

Affer untarzip, I set theses environment variables :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/

export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/hduser/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin

export PATH=~hduser/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:$PATH

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export M2_HOME=~hduser/apache-maven-3.2.5

export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=100
```

then I invoked

```
cd ~hduser/hadoop-2.9.0-src

/home/hduser/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/mvn  package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar
```

and 2h and 54 minutes later ... `BUILD SUCCESS`

now it's time to make it running...